# Create conditions in Eclipse plugin.xml

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, plugin.xml

Is there a way to create conditions (similar to if/else blocks) in the Eclipse plugin.xml's files.

I'm creating a Eclipse plugins in which I need to set a different value depending on the project facet, I'm getting the project facet using:

```
<with variable="projectFacet">
    <test property="org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.projectFacet" value="projectFacet" forcePluginActivation="true"/>
</with>
```

And then I have this code:

```
<item
    label="test"
    visible="false"
    id="test.test1"
    category="category1"
    description="test description">
</item>
```

At this momment I'm hardcoding `"category1"`, what I need is to select the correct category depending on the variable I got before, for example:

- facet1 should be on the category1
- facet2 should be on the category2

Someone knows how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Short answer is no. It is not clear which extension point `item` is for, but you may be able to have multiple items and use something like `visibleWhen` to control which ones show.

Comment: I see, then I will need to duplicate that block of code and surround each block with visibleWhen, I never used visibleWhen before so I will need to investigate about it, thanks.

Comment: Only certain extension points have visibleWhen, when they do it is a child element not surrounding.

Comment: Is there a way to verify that a given extension point have that property? I will need to verify it in several extension points

Comment: You read the documentation on the extension point. All elements are listed there.

Comment: The problem is that this are not extension points provided by Eclipse, and unfortunately there's no documentation about them :/